# Small <1MB Word 2013 file takes too long to save

Tags: microsoft-word

Couple of Word files (.docx) takes forever to save. Its a small document, 50 pages, 280 KB.

I followed all the usual methods, inspecting the documents and removing all the non-needed data. I only kept the headers and footers as I need them.

I also disabled Auto-save.

I also tried following the methods suggested [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/word-2013-extremely-slow-saving-and-pasting-plain/94718ebd-0a1a-4542-904a-33185a115ae2?page=2), but no joy. It gets really frustrating.

Has anyone faced a similar problem. Also, where can I find any external links to the file, its not in the Inspect Document module.

Edit: Saving the file in *doc format seems to fasten the save process, but still its not instantaneous.

Comment: Are you saving to a local directory or a network directory?

Comment: Local directory. On my computer only.

Comment: Try to launch MS Word at the command line, with "winword.exe /a" to  start with no add-ins or templates.

Comment: @dude: tried it, didn't work... Situation still the same...

Comment: try to rename a copy of your file to ...zip and extract it. How big are the extracted files. I often had a similar problem when drawing in word. The docx files are small, but the unzipped files are huge...

Comment: @Steffen: The extracted files are the same size.

Comment: have you tried another hard drive

Comment: @barlop: If there was an issue with hard drive, it would affect other files. This situation is with some word files, not all.

Answer (score 4):

File -> Settings -> Advanced ->Save and disable "Allow Background saves"

Comment: Does this actually help the time of normal saves?

Comment: This helped me, not sure it works for every slow save problem but it does help for some. This is a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what David suggested, also try going to

File -> Options -> Save tab and uncheck everything there. Word seems to do a lot of unnecessary things by default every time you save. I save by pressing CTRL+S instinctively every few minutes and all those extra steps just waste time.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind this would be:

- Whenever when it will happen just open task manager in your computer.
- Search for "paint"  in background processes.
- After finding that make a right click on it and select end task.

The problem will be solved.

Comment: I am unsure whether this is generally helpful. Paint is seldom a background process.